# Inlining CSS styles with nodemailer and handlebars

Tags: node.js, typescript, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I want to tranform my class styles to inline styles using nodemailer and handlebars.js. My template code is this:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <meta
          content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
          http-equiv="Content-Type"
        />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato"
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
        />
      </head>
      <body>
        <style>
          body {
            font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
          }
          .header {
            margin: 0 auto;
            min-width: 320px;
            max-width: 620px;
          }

          .logo {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
          }

          .center {
            text-align: center;
          }

          .title {
            margin: 0;
          }

          .invoice {
            font-size: 14;
            color: #71777D;
            line-height: 1.2;
            word-break: break-word;
          }

          .btn-success
          {
            color:#fff;
            background: #22caab;
            border-radius: 5px;
            transition:.15s linear;
            border-color: #22caab;

          }

          .powered {
            font-size: 12;
            line-height: 1.2;
            word-break: break-word;
            padding-top: 30px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
          }
        </style>
        <div class="header">
          <img
            class="logo"
            src="{{url}}img/teal_bto_head.png"
            width="150"
            alt="logo"
          >
          <h3 class="center title">
            Reset Password
          </h3>
          <p class="invoice center">
            Harmony recently received a request for a forgotten password.
          </p>

          <p class="invoice center">
            To change your password, please  press the next button:
          </p>
          <p  class="invoice center">
            <a href="{{url}}reset-password.php?t={{token}}" class="btn btn-success" >Continue Setup</a>
          </p>

          <p class="powered center">
            Powered by Qorus Inc.
          </p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And the nodemailer configuration is this:

```
const hbsConfig = {
        viewEngine: {
            extName: '.hbs',
            partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, '../../../../src/modules/hq-nd/templates/'),
            layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, '../../../../src/modules/hq-nd/templates/'),
            defaultLayout: ''
        },
        viewPath: path.join(__dirname, '../../../../src/modules/hq-nd/templates/'),
        extName: '.hbs'
    };

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'zzz',
            pass: process.env.SENDGRID_SECRET,
        },
    });
    transporter.use('compile', hbs(hbsConfig));
    const email = {
        from: "Boxtribe <123@gmail.com>",
        to: params.username,
        subject: 'Reset your zzz Password',
        template: 'forgot-password',
        context: {
            ...user,
            token: tokenRes.token,
            url: process.env.HARMONY_URL
        }
    };
    const response = await transporter.sendMail(email as Mail.Options);
```

How can I do this or is there a better way to add styles without doing it inline?